# Grub will not install with boot-repair or by any other means

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

I am currently trying to get Grub back. I have tried everything from reinstalling, to boot-repair, and even super boot manager. Nothing seems to work.

I have created a log with boot-repair [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1259258/).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

Ubiquity (the Ubuntu installer) installed Ubuntu in the wrong mode. You were affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1050940
It also removed the `boot` flag by mistake.

**Solution:**

1. Via [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted), set a `boot` flag on your sda1 partition.
2. Use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) --> `Recommended Repair`